How to use "either or"
What is the difference between these two?
1 Now, you either go with us or stay here
2 Now, you are either going with us or staying here
To me both sentences are interchangeable. Is that right? Please, provide some anwers?

The first one sounds like a rather abrupt request for the person to choose (I can imagine kidnappers giving their victim the choice of being taken with them or left behind as a prisoner!).
The second one sounds much milder. "We have made plans to cover both possibilities, but you can choose which you would prefer."
